# How can I get the text in a EmptyTableWidget in GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-2.2-celltable, celltable, gwt-celltable

My code is

```
CellTable celltable = new CellTable();    
celltable.setEmptyTableWidget(new Label("No"));
```

Here I want to get this "No" from CellTable

I tried as `cellTable.getEmptyTableWidget()).getElement().getInnerText()`

But I don't know how to get it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of `cellTable.getEmptyTableWidget()` was right already. You need to cast the Widget afterwards to what you added (in your case `Label`). So do something like this:

```
((Label)celltable.getEmptyTableWidget()).getText()
```

To receive the `no` from your table.

Regards,
noise

Comment: This is working:  cellTable.getEmptyTableWidget()).getElement().getInnerText();  Anyway thanks